# Javascript not updating inital parameters for bootstrap uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two fields in my form that contain the allowedFileTypes and maxFileSize that I need to allow for a selected document type.  These values are pulled from a db and updated based on the selection in a drop down list.  The js is pulling the values back correctly and the variables are populating.

The problem I have is that the values are picked up dynamically from within the form on the first selection but then do not update for further selections.   This code does not get reevaluated:

```
var fileTypes = $("#FileTypes").val();
var MaxFileSize = $("#MaxFileSize").val();
             $("#inputFile").fileinput({
                 maxFileCount: 1,
                 allowedFileExtensions: [fileTypes],
                 maxFileSize: MaxFileSize
             });
```

Any ideas?

I have looked at removing the script and reloading but did not have any success.  Asking the question here in case the issue is a general js one rather than a particular issue with the bootstrap uploader.

Browsers
- [ ] Google Chrome

Operating System
- [ ] Windows

Libraries

- jQuery version: 2.1.4
- bootstrap-fileinput version: 4.3.5

Comment: Can you change ID to Class for your fields and use the same with jQuery code ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make a difference. The fileTypes and maxFileSize variables get populated and update as expected but allowedFileExtensions and maxFileSize parameters do not get updated after script is first run.